# Sort the stack segments of barchart

Tags: vega-lite

I played with stacked bar charts and wanted to create the Spanish flag with Vega Lite.
I specified the stripes height and color in the data but don't manage to sort the individual stacks:

[image: Spanish Flag wrongly ordered]

I set the scale to null, so that the color is taken from the specified field.
I encoded the position of the stripe in the `pos` attribute, and want to sort the segements by that.
I've also tried to slightly vary the color of the red stripes, but that didn't help.

Spec:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v4.json",
  "description": "Fun with Flags",
  "data": {
    "values": [
      {"h": 5, "color": "#aa151b", "pos": 6, "country": "spain"},
      {"h": 5, "color": "#f1bf00", "pos": 4, "country": "spain"},
      {"h": 5, "color": "#aa152b", "pos": 2, "country": "spain"}
    ]
  },
  "width": {"step": 300},
  "mark": {"type": "bar"},
  "encoding": {
    "x": {"field": "country", "type": "nominal"},
    "y": {"field": "h", "type": "quantitative"},
    "color": { 
      "field": "color", 
      "scale": null,
      "type": "nominal",
      "sort": {"field": "pos", "op": "min", "order": "descending"}
    }
  }
}
```

Here's a link to the [Vega Editor with the Spec](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4IgJAzgxgFgpgWwIYgFwhgF0wBwqgegIDc4BzJAOjIEtMYBXAI0poHsDp5kTykBaADZ04JACyUAVhDYA7EABoQAEzjQATjRyZ289ADEGsgAQB3OjGP7BSMhEUqkmFKlDEkghmrQBtUDDQAViUoNkE2dTQQAGIkJABGQPimBxw2e1QANhC2I0x1AE8oiBwkGnkAXwV-IJzwyPRogDNkpoAGNtT0tDEcvMLi0vKQKprUYJBQ+qjYhMCAJhSlNIz5vtl8ovQSssqAXSqQc2V6NFAITDgcNABmDsPkdQBrM5BMApw4KKYkSMO4WShZTlMivAAeryaNDggmUUVC-SKSnenyisjYCHKHhGSi2oChMLh6ACyI+X3QAEcGEgNnQnDRSDjJmEIpDobD4SzIkpoB5ybIGIJBKTUeh0ZjZNieRFMGzCVEVg42Nd0BKlepVA0VGooADgbJQRUjRUgA).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of sorting the color encoding, I had to specify the order channel, as [described in the docs](https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/docs/stack.html#sorting-stack-order).

This gives me the following spec:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v4.json",
  "description": "Fun with Flags",
  "data": {
    "values": [
      {"h": 5, "color": "#aa152b", "pos": 6, "country": "spain"},
      {"h": 5, "color": "#f1bf00", "pos": 4, "country": "spain"},
      {"h": 5, "color": "#aa152b", "pos": 2, "country": "spain"}
    ]
  },
  "width": {"step": 300},
  "mark": {"type": "bar"},
  "encoding": {
    "x": {"field": "country", "type": "nominal"},
    "y": {"field": "h", "type": "quantitative"},
    "color": { 
      "field": "color", 
      "scale": null,
      "type": "nominal"
    },
    "order": {
      "field": "pos",
      "type": "quantitative"
    }
  }
}
```

And correct Spanish flag:

[image]

[Link to Vega Editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4IgJAzgxgFgpgWwIYgFwhgF0wBwqgegIDc4BzJAOjIEtMYBXAI0poHsDp5kTykBaADZ04JACyUAVhDYA7EABoQAEzjQATjRyZ289ADEGsgAQB3OjGP7BSMhEUqkmFKlDEkghmrQBtUDDQAViUoNkE2dTQQAGIkJABGQIAmJgccNntUADYQtiNMdQBPKIgcJBp5AF8FfyDc8Mj0aIAzeKZmgAYOtIy0MVz8opKyipBq2tRgkFCGqNiE5NSldMykgdkC4vRS8qqAXWqQc2V6NFAITDgcNABmLsPkdQBrM5BMQpw4KKYkSMO4WShZQVMivAAer2aNDggmUUVCg2KSnenyisjYCAqHjGSi2oChMLh6ACyI+X3QAEcGEgNnQnDRSDjpmEIpDobD4SzIkpoB5ybIGIJBKTUeh0ZjZNjDhFVI18eyiSAVg4UeSQFSaTpnDpGZU9UA)